# Where do I see the reason for the warning?

Tags: warnings, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting a warning in Chrome Developer but I can't figure out what causes it.
[image]

I looked [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#errors_and_warnings) but it offers no explanation. So far, the web page is super simple (basically 1 local html file + 1 css, no PHP/Javascript involved). I obviously clicked around (on the warning sign too) but nothing happens.

**UPDATE**

This really does look like a bug to me. Even with "Warnings" selected, I'm not seeing them here

[image]

but there's plenty of them...

**FINAL UPDATE**

Devtools' behavior really seems somewhat inconsistent here. I reported this as a bug with Goole.

Comment: The number you see next to the warning icon could be for CSS warnings.  Make sure you have CSS checked in the funnel-menu (see answer below for details on the funnel-menu).

Comment: Thank you. However, in some cases Chrome doesn't show the warnings even after doing so. I eventually reported this as a bug with Google.

Comment: @Ruben Could you post a link to the bug ticket you filed?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Looking at the bottom of the screen-capture you provided, I see the console filter is set to "Debug". The console filter options are located to the left of the warning symbol. If you change the filter to "Warnings" or "All", you should see the warning message associated with the warning symbol.

***Note the funnel button*** to the left of the "All" button.

[image]

You must check the type of output you want in the funnel-menu. The funnel menu is active for all filter-button options. So if you select the "Logs" button but have "Logging" unchecked in the funnel-menu, there will be no logging output.

Both funnel-menu and filter-buttons can be multi-selected. To select multiple filter buttons, Ctrl-click, Windows, or Cmd-click, OSX.

Comment: Thanks! I tried selecting "Warnings" a couple of times but to no avail. However, after selecting "All" and then "CSS" under "Filter" the warning message finally came up in the console window. Looks like a minor bug, I'll see whether I can replicate and report it.

Comment: Just had this one too. Pretty confusing that CSS warnings don't show by default cos of the filter but then are still counted at the bottom.